# Hive Over clause to run multiple reducers same time

Tags: hadoop, hive

How can I run/active such script to start all the reducers same time?

```
`SELECT id, map(
 'r02', string(PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY maps['k02']))
, 'r03', string(PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY maps['k03']))
, 'r04', string(PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY maps['k04']))
, 'r06', string(PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY maps['k06']))
, 'r09', string(PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY maps['k09']))
, 'r10', string(PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY maps['k10']))
, 'r11', string(PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY maps['k11'])))
FROM database
```

After the mapping is done, it seems only running one reducer at a time

```
INFO  : Map 1: 3/3      Reducer 2: 1(+1)/2      Reducer 3: 0/2  Reducer 4: 0/2  Reducer 5: 0/2  Reducer 6: 0/2  Reducer 7: 0/2Reducer 8: 0/2

INFO  : Map 1: 3/3      Reducer 2: 2/2  Reducer 3: 1(+1)/2      Reducer 4: 0/2  Reducer 5: 0/2  Reducer 6: 0/2  Reducer 7: 0/2Reducer 8: 0/2
```

How can I change the script to run it with all the reducers running parallel? Thanks, all.

Answer (score 0):

Please try -

```
set hive.exec.parallel=true;
```

Comment: Some explaination to it would be very much appreciated (*review*)

Comment: It still running one at a time. I just add this setting to the top of my script. Am i doing it wrong? I tried to add it my beeline initiation command, but still no luck.